# Create UITextField on UIView but can not get text input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield, gettext

I am using Xcode 6 and doing a small project on iOS 8, and I need to render some text onto the View.

My method is to create a UITextField on a UIView and as long as people type onit, the app redraw the View:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.renderTextView.textToRender = @"Please type something…";
    UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:self.renderTextView.frame];
    textField.opaque = NO;
    [self.renderTextView addSubview:textField];
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(updateLabelAndRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];  
}

- (void) updateLabelAndRefresh: (id)sender{
    self.renderTextView.textToRender = @"Hello World";

    // if text's length > 0 …
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.renderTextView.textToRender = self.textField.text;
    }

    [self.renderTextView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

But the problem is: no matter how I try, I can not get the actual text I type on my phone. and the console showed me that the text is **null**. I kept googling it but I stil can not work it out.

Do you guys have any solution? **Thank you** ;)

Comment: Well for one, you've locally defined the UITextField in viewDidLoad, so you shouldn't be able to get info from it in a different function.

Comment: In your .h file put `UITextField *textField;` then in the .m file in viewDidLoad omit the `UITextField *` part just leaving `textField = ...`

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Yes you are right! Thanks and it's one of the most stupid mistakes for me now…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below some error is there, give a look.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 //Here textField is local variable
 UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:self.renderTextView.frame];
 textField.opaque = NO;


}

- (void) updateLabelAndRefresh: (id)sender{
  self.renderTextView.textToRender = @"Hello World";

   // if text's length > 0 …
  if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {   //Then how come u getting self.textField here and using it as global one.
   //So you won't get access to that locally defined textField in viewDidLoad method.
     self.renderTextView.textToRender = self.textField.text;
 }
}
```

Please check your code and update me about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I make a small but silly mistake here…

Comment: whoever did vote it down ..please provide the reason for the same so atleast so that I could improve it if there is any issue with it. Thanks in advance and @TonyChol ur welcome.

Comment: I don't know who is voting… but your answer makes sense to me ;)

Comment: @TonyChol I know u didn't but it's for the person who did it without giving explanation about it.